# run mintty(cygwin) remotely from jenkins

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I am trying to run "configure" and "make" commands on windows platform (cygwin), from jenkins pipeline, running using this below command :

> bat "${CYGWIN_EXECTION} /cygdrive/c/JDK_BUILD_64_32/configure_64.sh
> ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ${JDK11_U_PATH_CYGWIN} ${params.snclabel} "

and

> bat "${CYGWIN_EXECTION} /cygdrive/c/JDK_BUILD_64_32/make_64.sh
> ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ${JDK11_U_PATH_CYGWIN} ${params.snclabel} "

where :
CYGWIN_EXECTION="C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -h start /bin/bash -l -e "

and
configure_64.sh contains below script:

> ./configure --with-freetype=bundled
> --with-tools-dir=/cygdrive/c/progra~2/micros~1/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/
> --with-jtreg=/cygdrive/c/jtreg-5.1-b01/ --with-version-pre=$SNCMID_VAR --with-version-build=$BUILD_NUMBER--with-version-opt=  --with-boot-jdk=/cygdrive/c/jdk-10.0.2 --with-boot-jdk-jvmargs="-Xmx4G -enableassertions"

and make_64.sh contains below script:

> ./make clean SPEC=build/windows-x86_64-normal-server-release/spec.gmk

When triggered from jenkins, the jenkins pipeline did start to execute but did not wait for the execution to finish (simply closes the cygwin dialog box, did not wait for execution to finish).

please advise the resolution to make it to wait for the "./configure" execution to finish (before moving forward to run "./make" ) ?

Comment: what do you mean remotely ? If is it really remote what is the scope of Mintty in the middle ?

Comment: Hello @matzeri- remotely,I meant trigger from jenkins and run on the windows slave node. Scope of mintty, for windows, we wanted to compile and generate windows based  binaries out of source,to use openjdk, we use cygwin (which comes with mintty by default), hence from minitty, we run configure  and make to generate windows based openjdk binaries. Any resolution is appreciated.

Comment: can you launch mintty or bash alone (interectively) without any script ?

Comment: @matzeri - yes, bash alone interactively, it works fine but from jenkins, its not. We wanted to automate  the execution.

Comment: I have not worked with the more recent versions of Jenkins, but with those I had experience with, you could not open any GUI component from it. Maybe this has changed, but for Debugging, can you start any Windows GUI program (for instance, a console window, or Notepad) from Jenkins?

Comment: It could be improper escaping of the command between Windows and Cygwin command line.